# Access: Updating multiple records with the same number

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, auto-update

I have a table of products, each of which have a serial numbers. There is also another field labelled SOP.

Basically when the product sells the SOP number (order number) will go in the field next to each serial number.

Before I continue, when I say scan this is because everything is barcoded.

I want to be able to create a form where I can scan in the SOP number and then for it to tab down where I can scan in all the serial numbers within that SOP.

It will then need to update each of the scanned in serial numbers with the relevant SOP number.

Any ideas?

Comment: How far have you gotten with this already?  Can you scan the SOP into a text box on your form?  Can you scan a serial number into another text box?

Comment: The current process is that there is a combobox setup with an autotab. Once serial scanned the SOP is scanned. Then serial then sop then serial.....etc. This is quite painful when some orders have 50+ serials.

Comment: Right, by avoiding the need to scan the same SOP again for each related serial number, you could could reduce that pain by almost 50%.  I geddit.  Have you ever created a form which includes a subform?

Comment: I can't say I have. Do you know of any tuts online?

Answer (score 1):

the steps you need to do to achieve this are

```
1) Create an Orders table with a field for the SOP number
2) Create an Order Details table with field for the SOP number
3) Create a form with a data source of the Orders table
4) Add a subform to the Orders form relating/linking the two forms on the SOP number
5) On the Orders form, disable "Tab Stop" for all fields except the SOP number field.
6) On the Orders form make sure that the "Enter Key Behavior" for the SOP number field     is "Default". If you don't do this, when the SOP number is canned, any subsequent scans will go into the same field.
7) On the Orders form add an "After Update" Event Procedure to
  i) Test if a value has been entered in the SOP number field
    and if so
  ii)Set focus on the SOP number on the Order Detail subform
    otherwise set focus to the SOP number field on the Orders form
8) On the Order Details subform, disable "tab Stop" for all fields except the serial number field.
9) On the Order Details subform make sure that the "Enter Key Behavior" for the serial number field is "Default".
10) Make sure the scanner is programmed to emulate an enter key press (CR/LF) after each scan, this is the default for most scanners I believe.
```

After scanning the SOP number, if an entry is found, the focus will shift to the serial number field on the subform, and you can then begin scanning serial numbers.

Example AfterUpdate event for SOP number field

```
Private Sub OrderSopNumber_AfterUpdate()
  If Me.OrderSopNumber > "" Then
    Me.sfmOrderDetail.Form.OrderDetailSerialNumber.SetFocus
  Else
    Me.OrderSopNumber.SetFocus
  End If
End Sub
```